# Can't connect to router settings through Ethernet

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ethernet

I have a D-Link router. I want to connect to the settings menu (using `192.168.1.1`) in order to do things like port forwarding. I am unable to connect to this address while using Ethernet (Chrome just tries to load the page forever and nothing happens), but when connecting through WiFi I can load the page. Why might this be happening? I'm using Windows 10.

**Update:** Tried again with Edge and IE. Same result, page just hangs and doesn't load; I don't even get the sign-in prompt.

**Update 2:** Used the commands `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew` and `ipconfig /flushdns`. Page now doesn't load at all; Chrome just says

> The 192.168.1.1 page isn't working. `192.168.1.1` didn't send any data. `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

**Update 3:** Doesn't even work with WiFi now. I changed nothing.

**Update 4:** After reading some stuff about Java and how Chrome no longer supports Java plugins (or something) I decided to try updating to the latest version of Java. Internet Explorer now says

> This page can't be displayed

and Chrome says

> The 192.168.1.1 page isn't working. 192.168.1.1 didn't send any data.

**Update 5:** Talked to a TalkTalk agent about the problem, no change unfortunately. My router is a D-Link DSL-3680

Comment: Are you connected to a wire LAN port and not the WAN port?
(WAN port is the one usually facing the external network and hence the management interface is usually blocked from that port)

Comment: @Hennes Yes I think so. I have an Ethernet cable plugged into the slot labelled LAN and the appropriate light is on

Comment: Is the current IP of the computer in the `192.168.1.x` range?

Comment: @dxiv Yes. `192.168.1.9`

Comment: if it's now not working over either, I would restart the D-Link.  After that, go in and check that you have enabled the management interface for the LAN interface, some routers you can specify which interface(s) the admin interface is available on.

Comment: @Adrien I've restarted it already multiple times with no effect. How do I check that the admin interface is enabled?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15089/windows-change-tcp-ip-settings Follow the instructions here to make sure your computer is obtaining both IP and DNS automatically. Make sure you select the Ethernet adapter you're having problems with from the Network and Sharing Centre.

Comment: @BigChris Both ipv4 and ipv6 are set to automatic

Comment: Even the DNS portion of the settings screen? Additionally, it may be worthwhile forcing the network adapter speed to 100MBps/Full duplex as it may be that you have a gigabit connection that;s not correctly auto-negotiated...

Comment: @BigChris Yep. Both radiobuttons are set to automatic on both protocols

Comment: @BigChris What do you mean by forcing the adapter speed to 100MBps? How do I do that?

Comment: Open Network and Sharing Center -> Go to "Change adapter settings" -> Right click your Ethernet card -> "Properties" -> Go through the tabs and you'll find something to do with "Speed and Duplex". It will probably be set to "Auto negotiate" and may be causing the problem. We're trying to rule things out at the moment :)

Comment: If you have network/Internet connection but only the router admin page does not work, the problem is most probably with the router. I suggest that you do not play too much with your network parameters, but rather do a hard-reset of the router (return to factory default). Knowing the router exact model will be useful.

Comment: @harrymc I'm out right now and can't post the router model but I will update with that information as soon as I can

Comment: Any news for the above ?

Comment: @imulsion get into your router via WiFi, and check the DHCP option, if is it disabled, then enable it and restart your router and try to connect to it through different LAN port.

Comment: Did you try a different Ethernet port on the device just in case? Have you tried powering off all wired and wireless devices connected to it, and then restart the router, wait five minutes or so and then startup the ONE wired device and and see what results you get? Would you consider a router **Factory Reset** on the router? Please answer all these questions and give those a try just in case it's as simple as that and these are acceptable solution in your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get anything back, and you've already tried resetting the router, then try booting a linux liveCD on the PC and accessing your router via browser on the linux environment over ethernet. If that works then we can assume the issues lies with your network configuration on the Windows 10 machine - something like a proxy setting, protocol setting, or driver is causing issues. Troubleshoot those manually or reset to factory defaults.

If linux can't access the router, we can assume the problem is hardware-based. Test as many of the following as possible:

- Use a different ethernet port on the PC (might have to add a NIC if
  you have an old one laying around)
- Use a different ethernet port on
  the router
- Use a different ethernet cable
- Try a different router
- Try a shorter cable

This process should step you through the remaining possibilities. With every part of the chain tested, there is no possibility of the problem remaining after proper implementation of this process, unless you happen to be operating in an unusually high radiation or electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the IP address of the router
(type Cmd from the start button and then type IPCONFIG)

It should be under "Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection" (wired Connection)
The default Gateway should read 192.168.1.1 - The same as your "Wireless LAN Adapter Wireless Connection" setting. That is the address of the router.

If your wired connection reads Media Disconnected, Check or replace the cable.

Comment: We've been through this in the comments. I have the right address, my browser just won't load the page

Comment: I don't have a D-link any more, but my old one had an ip of 192.168.0.1

Comment: This one is definitely 192.168.1.1

Comment: I see you re-started the router, did you try the Re-set button to reset it to factory default?

Wat is the model?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities for losing access to your router:

**The most likely reason:**

1. You've accidentally set the IP obtained from Wi-Fi, as the only Management IP. So, if after `ipconfig /release` `ipconfig /renew` you obtained IP `192.168.1.9` and you lost access to management service, then probably you can access it again by setting your IP manually to one of the addresses in the range `192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.8` with the last one being the most likely address to solve your problem (last address before renewing your IP). Try to do that from Wi-Fi, since it was the last accessible workstation. If it doesn't help, a factory-reset is the only possible way IMO.

**Just for your consideration, Not related to your problem since you had access to WEB panel using default port:**

2. You've disabled **Management over HTTP** for LAN zone. There's a chance that other management options like `telnet` are still accessible. Try to enable *Telnet Client* feature in your windows (if not already enabled) by going to `appwiz.cpl> Turn windows features on or off> Telnet Client` and open `cmd` then run `telnet 192.168.1.1` if it asks for *username* and *password*, then you are able to manage your router and even enable *HTTP web panel*.
3. There's also a chance that you changed default port for Management services, it's `HTTP:80` and `Telnet:23` by default. If you changed both, then there's no way to recover access than remembering the port, or reset to factory defaults.

Comment: OK so I tried the things suggested in this answer. A 30-30-30 factory reset didn't fix the problem, the browser still says `the 192.168.1.1 page isn't working`. I then tried point 2, enabling `telnet`. I ran the command and it exited with `Could not open connection to the host on port 23: connect failed`. Since it tried to connect on port 23 I guess point 3 isn't the reason either.

Comment: Did your computer obtained an IP?? (make sure your network card is configured to obtain IP address automatically) If not, the router is probably broken. If yes, there's something wrong with management console of your router. In both cases, you should contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my linksys router and even a factory reset wouldn't work.  Weirdly, a factory reset followed by plugging the router into my network (LAN) but not plugging it in to the power outlet brought it back:
1.With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset button on back of unit for 30 seconds
2.Without releasing the reset button, unplug the unit and hold reset for another 30 seconds
3.Plug the unit into your computer with an ethernet cable STILL holding the reset button a final 30 seconds
4.Wait for a full minute before plugging your router back in.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1) Be completely sure you have only "one" DHCP server in your net; your Dlink router. (Wireshark traffic captures can give you an idea if your router is the ONLY DHCP service available and if it is assigning the right IPs or not)

2) Factory reset usually set Dlink routers management port to 192.168.0.1

3) Be sure yo do not have any MAC filter preventing WEB management.

Answer (score 0):

Windows ran a network diagnostics for me and found the DHCP had been switched off on my laptop. I pressed the option to allow diagnostics to fix the problem and it did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).